# Unable to handle SAML 2.0 unsolicited response in Jboss EAP how to solve?

Tags: jboss7.x

I am getting the following error: Could not handle SAML 2.0 unsolicited response when clicking the link as pictured below...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1AvI.png)

the toturial of which I am developing the project is this -> https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/how_to_set_up_sso_with_saml_v2/index#linking_to_sps

I have the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix0Np.png)

As described by the A Walk Through section, once the user is authenticated the IdP shows a page with links to all service provider applications. A link will usually look like this:

?
[Sales](http://localhost:8080/idp?SAML_VERSION=2.0&TARGET=http://localhost:8080/sales-post/)

Note that the link above redirects the user to the IdP passing the TARGET query parameter, whose value is the URL to the target service provider application. Once the user clicks the link above, the IdP will extract the TARGET parameter from the request, build a SAML v2.0 Response and redirect the user to the target URL. When the user hits the service provider it will be automatically authenticated.